# Addition theorem for angular velocity --> "addition theorem for angles"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, education, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm wondering if it is possible to go from the addition theorem for angular velocity to the "addition theorem for angles".
For example (I used the same notations of [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body#Addition_theorem_for_angular_velocity)):

$${^N\!\omega^B} = {^N\!\omega ^D} + {^D\!\omega ^B}$$

$${^N\!\theta^B} = {^N\!\theta^D} + {^D\!\theta^B}$$

Comment: your equation is not valid If $\omega \neq \omega \left( \theta ,\dfrac {d\theta }{dt}\right) $

Comment: Hello @Eli, do you mean that is valid only in 2D?

Comment: Hallo @ Gennaro yes but also valid for small rotations in 3D

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Eli; it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following is true
$$\frac{\text d\  {^X\!\theta ^Y}}{\text d\ t}=^X\!\omega ^Y$$

For each $X=\{N,D\}$ and $Y=\{B,D\}$, then I don't see why not. As long as it's all about the same axis.